# How to add a foreign key to the username. Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

During serialization, i noticed that the `post_author` Foreign Key of the `Post` model is referencing the id of the creator and thus, i can't display the username of the creator in the REST API, only the post_author id.
How can i add the username of the post_creator, so that it is readable to other users, when i fetch the data on the frontend?

**models.py** // CustomUser = the Creator of the post.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    fav_color = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=120)

class Post(models.Model):
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py** user model and post model serialization

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Currently unused in preference of the below.
    """
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        # as long as the fields are the same, we can just use this
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**single post from the API**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "post_title": "first_post",
    "post_body": "qwe1",
    "created_date": "2020-11-17T19:30:55Z",
    "published_date": null,
    "post_author": 1
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the serializer:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_author_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="post_author.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [post_author_username, post_title, post_body, created_data, published_data]
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like adding the `post_author_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="post_author.username")` and leaving the `fields = '__all__'`also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can to specify the post_author serializer in your PostSerializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_author=CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)